# ExpressionEngine use

Tags: content-management-system, updates, expressionengine

My company has used ExpressionEngine for their CMS service and currently we have been discussing changes to our website and whether or not Expression is the something to keep or to search for a new/better CMS.  I notice that topics on this subject matter seem to end in 2014 so it is difficult to get information on uses and updates that could prove beneficial.  It would be great to know your thoughts on this CMS or better options that a non-profit group could look into.

I am the web associate for my team and I am trying to expand my education on design and CMS uses, so any thoughts are appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Taking a CMS beyond it's basic functions is really about the platforms documentation. Wordpress, EE, Craft, and a few others have great documentation.

Obviously wordpress is the talk of the town, but EE is still supported and maintains it's flexibility.